# Как создать ссылку на  элемент по которому был произведен клик

Tags: jquery

Приветсвую всех!!!Люди добрые, подскажите как создать ссылку на  элемент по которому был произведен клик, для дальнейшего использования в скрипте,пробовал делать так: задаю глобальную переменную var object_target, после чего в нее пробую прописать элемент по которому был сделан щелчек мышью, пробовал использовать object_target дальше в скрипте ничего не получается, как быть?

```
$(function(){
var object_target;
    $('.map_icon').click(function(e) {
        object_target = $(this);
        });

});
```

Comment: Переменная `object_target` у вас не является глобальной. Её область видимости - это функция внутри `$()`;

Answer (score 1):

Просто object_target  вынесите с функции. Если не хотите засорять глобальную область то ваш код оберните в функцию еще одну, всё.

Answer (score 0):

Ну как вариант

```
window.object_target = $(this);
```

Но это быдкокод.

Правильно будет создать класс

```
var App = function(){
  this.object_target = null;
  this.getObjectTarget = function(){
    return this.object_target;
};
this.setObjectTarget = function(val){
    this.object_target = val;
}

}
```

Далее создаем экземпляр.

```
var app = new App();
```

Устанавливаем значение

```
app.setObjectTarget(123);
```

Получаем значение

```
console.log(app.getObjectTarget());
```

Comment: Какая конкретно разница, что он создаст новое замыкание если у него уже есть одно. Зачем делать App, его делать глобальным?